# Las peticiones HttpsURLConnection no me funcionan en Glassfish 5

Tags: java, glassfish

Quiero hacer una petición https haciendo uso de las clases java.net.URL y javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection para validar un formulario usando el servicio recaptcha de Google.
Para iniciar la prueba tengo este código desde un servlet para comprobar que la conexión se inicia correctamente.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int code=con.getResponseCode();
    String codigo=Integer.toString(code);
    response.getWriter().append("Codigo de respuesta a peticion https://www.google.com ").append(codigo);
```

Este código invocado haciendo uso de un servidor Glassfish 5 siempre genera el siguiente error:

```
 [2018-11-08T12:24:13.224+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=32 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1541676253224] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[servlets.Controller]: Servlet.service() for servlet servlets.Controller threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.<init>(Lsun/security/ssl/ProtocolVersion;Lsun/security/ssl/CipherSuite;Ljava/util/Collection;Lsun/security/ssl/SessionId;Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHello(ClientHandshaker.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:984)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:919)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    at servlets.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:686)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

El mismo código invocado desde un servidor Apache Tomcat 9 funciona perfectamente.
¿Tengo que configurar algún parámetro en el servidor Glassfish 5 para poder abrir conexiones https?
¿Se trata de algún bug de Glassfish?
Gracias.

Comment: Tiene pinta que la implementación de SSL de Glasfish usa una versión distinta a de Tomcat y por lo tanto no encuentra el método buscado.

Comment: Parece que es un bug de Glassfish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383650/sun-security-ssl-sslsessionimpl-not-found. En todo caso (visto que el bug es algo antiguo e igual ya se ha resuelto) la otra cosa a comprobar es que estés usando el JDK adecuado.

Comment: Aunque viendo esto, parece más cuestión del JDK que del Glassfish: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213282

Comment: Fijate la versión de java que estás usando si matchea la versión de Glassfish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733840/glassfish-5-0-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: @SJuan76. Gracias la solución que se aporta en ese enlace me ha funcionado. Consiste en eliminar la carpeta sun de [glassfish5_home]/glassfish/modules/endorsed/grizzly-npn-bootstrap.jar

Comment: @Juan. Gracias por contestar. No he tenido tiempo de cambiar la versión del jdk para hacer la prueba. Pero estoy usando Glassfish 5.0 con una versión jdk1.8.0_181. Por lo que parece ese puede ser el problema. En cuanto haga la prueba informo si ha funcionado.